# To use d3.js methods, Does data need to be in Json format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, d3.js

How can i use methods like nest() with data in array of arrays format rather than array of objects ?

Edit: For instance, accessing values with attribute name like d.name is not possible for me as data is dynamic. Attribute names & their values changes with user input file. Instead of accessing by d.name, i want to access by index value d[0] upon user selection of specific attribute.

Apart from that, do i need to use server to use d3.js as specified here: http://learnjsdata.com/getting_started.html ?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather broad and difficult to really see what you are asking.  So, I'll answer the one part of it that's concrete:

> How can i use methods like nest() with data in array of arrays format rather than array of objects?

`d3` provides what are called `accessor` methods which are just functions returning a piece of your data.  In most examples you'll see arrays of objects and these accessor functions returning a property of the object.  There's nothing stopping you, though, from returning a part of the inner array.  Here's your nest with an array of arrays.  I've written the [key accessor](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nest_key) function to return a part (the first value) of the array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [
      [0, 1],
      [0, 2],
      [0, 3],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 2],
      [1, 3]
    ];

    var entries = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })
      .entries(data);

    console.log(entries);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @krishnadamarla, doesn't look like you have an array of arrays, but an **array of strings** (that are numbers with commas in between).  You really need to create a *reproducible* code sample of what you are trying to do...

Comment: (sorry for deleting comment, i thought the same to process data before) ,Thanks for your answer. But, my data is rather big. for instance, [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,.....16000], [1,2,3,....16000],.....[ ], [ ]...until 46 arrays]. these 46 arrays are columns with row values until 16000. i wrote a nest function similar to what you specified to nest array 30(column 30) over the data. But this is returning like imgur.com/a/HOLvj instead of seperate key as key:0, key:10 etc.